# Java, Simple JUnit test. Set value to zero

Tags: java, class, methods, junit

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;    
@Test
        public void testZero() 
        {   
            Calculator test = new Calculator();
            int acc = 1234;
            test.zero();
            assertEquals(0,acc);
        }
```

// Production code no include Test

```
class Calculator 
{
    public void zero(){
        acc = 0;
    }
}
```

I want to test zero() method which is in Calculator class and set the acc value to 0. I created JUnit test and wrote simple test. I have no idea why it still doesn't work. I carry out JUnit test first time and have no more idea how it should be written.

Im testing in Eclipse. Eclipse dont show me Error, but show thats 0 is not equal to acc.

Comment: can you please provie more information of how it does not work? errors, stacktraces, etc.

Comment: I think you are mixing test and production code.

Comment: Im testing in Eclipse. Eclipse dont show me Error, but show thats 0 is not equal to acc.

Comment: Its not in the same file, and production code no include test.

Comment: could you please post both (test and production code)

Comment: `test.zero();` only sets `acc` defined in `Calculator` to zero. And, you'll need an accessor in `Calculator` to get the value and then compare.

Comment: I'll posted the source code suggested by @srkavin
Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;    

public class CalculatorTest {

  @Test
  public void testZero() 
  {   
    Calculator test = new Calculator();
    test.zero();
    assertEquals(0,test.getAcc());
  }
}
```

Production code:

```
class Calculator 
{
    private int acc;

    public void zero(){
        acc = 0;
    }
    public int getAcc(){
        return acc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You set totally unrelated variable values as the `acc` variable in `Calculator` has nothing to do with the `acc` variable in your test class (only their names are the same but nothing more). If you want `Calculator` to set your `acc` variable value in your test then `zero()` should return a 0 value and test the returned value in your test.

Comment: Even then, He's using assertsEqual over `acc` and `0`, so It should throw an error.